# MapStruct Vs Normal Java Code - Which is more performing?

Tags: java, java-11, mapstruct

I have a source POJO and a target POJO, with 10 fields having getters and setters.

1. If I use MapStruct to map source POJO to target POJO, a precompiled class file will be created by MapStruct which will then be compiled by JVM.
2. Write normal manual java code to map source to target by accessing getter and setter methods.

Will there be any improvement in performance regarding latency of JVM if we use MapStruct over normal manual mapping code? Or, in this case, are we using MapStruct just for saving developer's time to write manual mapping code?

Comment: The code created by MapStruct usually just calls getters and setter, with the necessary (and sometimes unnecessary) `null` checks. I doubt you can find noticeable performance differences. Nanoseconds maybe, microseconds unlikely, milliseconds definitely not.

Comment: You can also have a look at https://github.com/arey/java-object-mapper-benchmark for some mapping benchmarks. In addition to that, MapStruct strives to generate code similar like it has been manually written, so there shouldn't be any big difference in performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some benchmarks at https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks

In my opinion, there is no difference in performance

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).